# Save and Load Data from Application.persistentDataPath works in Unity, but not on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, persistent-storage

I'm building an app that needs to save and load user created data to the persistent data path. When I play it in the Unity Editor it works perfectly, but when I try it on iOS, I get this error:

```
Uploading Crash Report
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at CustomModeScript.LoadSavedModes () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at CustomModeScript.Initialize (System.String fromPanel) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MainSettingsPanelScript.OnControlModes () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, System.Boolean pressed, System.Boolean released) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

It used to be an ioexception: Sharing violation on path error, but now it's the error above after I refactored my Load function. The issue is currently happening when I try to load the data (I can't really tell if it is saving or not)

Here is the functions for Save and Load (Retrieve)

```
public void SaveModes()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserCustomModes.jl");
        List<Mode> data = new List<Mode>();

        data = savedModes;
        
        bf.Serialize(file , data);
        file.Close();
    }

    // Retrieve saved modes if they exist 
    public List<Mode> RetrieveSavedModes()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserCustomModes.jl"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserCustomModes.jl", FileMode.Open);
            List<Mode> storedModesFile = bf.Deserialize(file) as List<Mode>;

            savedModes = storedModesFile;
            file.Close();
        }

        return savedModes;
    }
```

Here is the code that is calling the load function:

```
// Populate mode view with saved modes
    private void PopulateModeView()
    {
        ClearCustomModes();
        Debug.Log("Loading Modes: " + Manager.savedModes.Count);
        if (Manager.savedModes.Count > 0)
        {
            //Debug.Log("More than 0 modes present");
            var index = 0;
            foreach (var savedMode in Manager.savedModes)
            {
                var modeItem = Instantiate(customModeItemPrefab, customModeSectionTransform);
                modeItem.GetComponent<CustomModeItemScript>().Initialize(savedMode, index, this, mainSettingsPanelScript);
                generatedModeButtons.Add(modeItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the LoadSavedModes Function:

```
private void LoadSavedModes()
    {
        RemoveAllModeButtons();
        Manager.savedModes = Manager.RetrieveSavedModes();
        Debug.Log("[UNITY] Retrieve Modes Count: " + Manager.savedModes.Count);
        PopulateModeView();
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure why the code does not work yet, but do [`not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0) use `BinaryFormatter` as it is insecure. An alternative is [`ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-5.0) and [`WriteAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=net-5.0).

Comment: The error message is quite clear. There should not be an issue with `PersistentPath`, as that looks correct. The error is saying there is a `null` reference when attempting to call the method `LoadSavedModes` inside of one of the `Initialize` calls. Can you share this method? Do you default your data in case a user has no save data? What are you saving/loading? Is it primitive data types or are you attempting to save/load more complex types such as `GameObjects`?

Comment: Just realized I had linked the wrong doc for my original comment, [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) are the reasons to avoid `BinaryFormatter`. I had linked the original use case doc before - my bad.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @TEEBQNE. I've updated my question with the LoadSavedModes function. I also sett the savedModes object to a new List<Mode> when I declare the variable as well as before I call the RetrieveSavedModes function. The data is primitive data, and not GameObjects

Comment: Are you by chance able to run your app while connected to `XCode`? It will make debugging for you a lot easier as `XCode` will display the live printouts from your application. Finding the printouts, you can find exactly where it breaks based on what gets printed out before and/or after the `null` reference. I would also still advise swapping from using `BinaryFormatter` to an alternative. I see a few places there *could* be a `null` reference, but it is hard to say exactly.

Comment: @TEEBQNE, yes the error is from Xcode, in Unity it runs with no issues. The null exception is thrown on “Manager.savedModes.count” in the LoadSavedModes function. That’s the strange part, in the Unity Player the app runs with no error, but in iOS Xcode debugger I get the error

Comment: I wouldn't mind the dowvote SO is weird. As for the error, from what I can tell it means `Manager.RetrieveSavedModes()` sets the value to null. I have not used `BinaryFormatter` recently as it is obsolete, so I'm not sure if there's an OS specific issue. I believe adding the line `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");` before you serialize when just on iOS should resolve the issue. I still heavily recommend changing your implementation. Let me know if adding this works for you.

Comment: @TEEBQNE, yes I tried adding ```//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");``` but I still get the same error. I will be changing it to something that I can secure, but I need this to work for now until then.

Comment: Are by chance serializing a class that's is not marked as serializable?

Comment: @TEEBQNE, the Mode Class is serializable, but not the List<Mode>.

Comment: The more I read into it, `BinaryFormatter` seems to have a lot of issues. I found a few posts that have had issues similar to yours with deserializing lists of serialized custom classes, and their solution was to swap their serialization method. I can write up an example on how to use JSON if you'd like. Might solve your issue.

Comment: @TEEBQNE, that would actually be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Added a snippet. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my personal templated `Save/Load` script. I know it works for all platforms currently listed in the function `GetFilePath`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Saves, loads and deletes all data in the game
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public static class SaveLoad<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Save data to a file (overwrite completely)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="folder"></param>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    public static void Save(T data, string folder, string file)
    {
        // get the data path of this save data
        string dataPath = GetFilePath(folder, file);

        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);
        byte[] byteData;
        
        byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);

        // create the file in the path if it doesn't exist
        // if the file path or name does not exist, return the default SO
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dataPath)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dataPath));
        }

        // attempt to save here data
        try
        {
            // save datahere
            File.WriteAllBytes(dataPath, byteData);
            Debug.Log("Save data to: " + dataPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // write out error here
            Debug.LogError("Failed to save data to: " + dataPath);
            Debug.LogError("Error " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Load all data at a specified file and folder location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="folder"></param>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Load(string folder, string file)
    {
        // get the data path of this save data
        string dataPath = GetFilePath(folder, file);

        // if the file path or name does not exist, return the default SO
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dataPath)))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("File or path does not exist! " + dataPath);
            return default(T);
        }

        // load in the save data as byte array
        byte[] jsonDataAsBytes = null;

        try
        {
            jsonDataAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dataPath);
            Debug.Log("<color=green>Loaded all data from: </color>" + dataPath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to load data from: " + dataPath);
            Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
            return default(T);
        }

        if (jsonDataAsBytes == null)
            return default(T);

        // convert the byte array to json
        string jsonData;

        // convert the byte array to json
        jsonData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonDataAsBytes);

        // convert to the specified object type
        T returnedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(jsonData);

        // return the casted json object to use
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(returnedData, typeof(T));
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Create file path for where a file is stored on the specific platform given a folder name and file name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FolderName"></param>
    /// <param name="FileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string GetFilePath(string FolderName, string FileName = "")
    {
        string filePath;
#if UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
        // mac
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, ("data/" + FolderName));

        if (FileName != "")
            filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, (FileName + ".txt"));
#elif UNITY_EDITOR_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
        // windows
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, ("data/" + FolderName));

        if(FileName != "")
            filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, (FileName + ".txt"));
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        // android
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, ("data/" + FolderName));

        if(FileName != "")
            filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, (FileName + ".txt"));
#elif UNITY_IOS
        // ios
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, ("data/" + FolderName));

        if(FileName != "")
            filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, (FileName + ".txt"));
#endif
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

Here is an example to use the script

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
         testData = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> testData = new List<int>();
}

public class TestMono : MonoBehaviour
{
     private string testFolder = "folder";
     private string testFile = "file";

     private List<int> myList = new List<int>();

     private void Awake()
     {
          // the ?? is a null comparison so if the value returns null, it generates new data
          TestClass loadedData = SaveLoad<TestClass>.Load(folder, file) ?? new TestClass();

          myList = loadedData.testData;
     }

     private void SaveData()
     {
         TestClass dataToSave = new TestClass
         {
              testData = myList
         };
          
         SaveLoad<TestClass>.Save(dataToSave, folder, file);
     }
}
```

The above snippet is untested but is the general use-case for the `Save/Load` script.

Comment: Thank you @TEEBQNE, this is much appreciated. Do you think this could be a bug in Unity3D? Because this code was working in 2019.4, but now in 2020.3 it isn't working

Comment: As `BinaryFormatter` is slowly being deprecated or is already deprecated it could just be in newer versions some support of it is removed in favor of newer methods. It could be a bug or could be a purposeful push to remove the use of it all together.

Comment: I should've just gone with your suggestion in the first place, would've been quicker :). Thank you very much

Comment: @RobertH Anytime! Glad it worked out for you.